# javascript: functionname() instread of functionname()

Tags: javascript, html

Why some developers use,

```
<input type="button" onClick="javascript:function-name()">
```

instead of

```
<input type="button" onClick="function-name()">
```

Please help me to solve this matter.

Comment: Totally legit question, but `function-name()` won't work, the caracter `-` is not accepted in any JS name, it means "minus". Your function name is equivalent to `function - name()`. You should write `function_name()` or `functionName()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because they probably just don't know better and think they have to use `javascript:` whenever they use JS in an HTML attribute.

---

In an event handler attribute, `javascript:` is nothing but a [**label**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/label) and is entirely useless.

However, it is necessary in `href` attributes, but it has a completely different meaning: It is a pseudo-protocol, which tells the browser to interpret the remainder of the "URI" as JavaScript.

(not to mention that using JS inside an `href` is considered bad practice)